# Using regex in python to search for floats, and replace them with reduced float precision in a string?

Tags: python, regex

Apologies if this has been answered already - I tried looking it up, but maybe my search terms (same as my title) were bad.

Let's assume I have a string like this, which I don't have control over:

```
astr = "A 5.02654824574 (14.710000000000008, -19.989999999999995, -0.8) <-> s[10]: A 5.02654824574 (-29.11999999999999, 52.78, -0.8)"
```

I would like to process this string, so that floats in it are displayed with arbitrary amount of float precision - say 3 decimals. Since this would work on a level of a string, I wouldn't expect the process to account for correct rounding - simply for removal of decimal point string characters.

I'm aware I could do, as per [Python: Extract multiple float numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054733/python-extract-multiple-float-numbers-from-string) :

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')
for i in p.findall(astr): print i
```

... which prints:

```
5.02654824574
14.710000000000008
19.989999999999995
0.8
5.02654824574
29.11999999999999
52.78
0.8
```

.... however, I'm getting lost at which regex captures I need to do in a search and replace, so - say, for `n_float_precision_decimals = 4`, - I'd get this string as output (with the above string as input):

```
"A 5.0265 (14.7100, -19.9899, -0.8) <-> s[10]: A 5.0265 (-29.1199, 52.78, -0.8)"
```

So basically, the regex would be taking into account that if there is a smaller number of decimals present already, it would not truncate decimals at all.

Is this possible to do, in a single `re.sub` operation, without having to write explicit `for` loops as above, and manually constructing the output string?

Comment: Might you prefer rounding the number to the desired precision instead, rather than just truncating? eg `-19.9900` instead of `-19.9899`, it's not hard to do at all

Comment: or `-19.99` alone, it'd probably look nicer

Answer (score 2):

Got it - thanks to [Reduce float precision using RegExp in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947938/reduce-float-precision-using-regexp-in-swift) ( which popped up in SO suggestions only after I finished typing the entire question (during which time, all I got were irrelevant results for this particular question) `:)` ):

```
>>> pat=re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d{2})\d+')
>>> pat.sub(r'\1', astr)
'A 5.02 (14.71, -19.98, -0.8) <-> s[10]: A 5.02 (-29.11, 52.78, -0.8)'
```

... or:

```
>>> nfloatprec=4
>>> pat=re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d{'+str(nfloatprec)+'})\d+')
>>> pat.sub(r'\1', astr)
'A 5.0265 (14.7100, -19.9899, -0.8) <-> s[10]: A 5.0265 (-29.1199, 52.78, -0.8)'
```